# Sitecore Forms - Resume Multi-Page Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

We're looking to create a Sitecore Form for invitees only (via a unique URL). As there are around 60 questions to answer, we'd like to split this across multiple pages.

We also have the requirement to allow the user to partially complete the form (e.g. complete 2 pages out of 5) and to be able to resume the form completion by returning to the unique URL.

Data from the form is sensitive in nature, and will not be stored in the Sitecore Forms DB, so we cannot re-populate completed form fields on resumption. We will, however, know how many pages have been completed previously. Resuming will always start from the first incomplete page, and it won't be possible to return to previously-completed pages.

Is there a way to accomplish resuming multi-page forms with Sitecore Forms? As an alternative I'm considering chaining a series of 5 forms together, and using some kind of controller to determine which form to direct the user to. Does anyone have experience of something similar?

Comment: I don't think you can implement your requirement in Sitecore forms. I would suggest building a custom control for this

Comment: If you're not saving the form data in the Sitecore Forms DB I'm assuming you have a custom Save action that saves the data to a place that you trust? You could add that action to every "next" button and and have your submit-action be smart enough to update the existing entry in your trusted storage? Also there's existing submit-actions that redirect the user to a form-page so look into that code and either fire it upon loading the form or have a first page without any input fields and give the first next-button a custom submit action that checks where the user was and redirects to that page.

Comment: Thanks both. @asontu I think that sounds like what I was thinking - having some sort of form orchestrator which identifies the previous submission state and directs you to the appropriate page. The Next buttons would perform the partial-save actions and direct you to the following page, with the final Submit bringing the submission together. I'll dive into the code to see how the page redirect actions work and build out a proof of concept.